# Oracle join using ON

Tags: oracle, join

I need to achieve beblow scenario using "ON". So far i have used + for joins

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1,
TAB2,
TAB3
WHERE TAB1.X=TAB2.X(+)
AND TAB1.Y  =TAB3.Y(+)
AND TAB2.Z  =TAB3.Z
```

Comment: You should clarify what you want to achieve. The last condition in where clause invalidates semantics of (+), because Z field comes null for non-joined rows but it can be not-null only for joined rows. The query seems to be senseless.

Answer (score 1):

The last inner-join cancels out all the outer joins.  This is the equivalent query in ANSI syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1
JOIN TAB2
  ON TAB1.X = TAB2.X
JOIN TAB3
  ON TAB1.Y = TAB3.Y
 AND TAB2.Z = TAB3.Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Albeit the difference between joining and filtering is fuzzy, I think this variant expresses sematics in best way:

```
select *
from tab1 
left join tab2 on tab1.x = tab2.x
left join tab3 on tab1.y = tab3.y
where tab2.z = tab3.z
```

Comment: But the where clause will turn the outer join back into an inner join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, agree with you, but this happens in original query too. Asked author for comment.